# How to scale a pixel-drawing function in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I have a function like this:

```
public void setPixel(int x, int y, boolean on);
```

It sets a virtual black and white pixel, given whether it is `on` or not.

How can I call this function so the resulting display will be four times larger?

I tried this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 3;
setPixel(x, y, true);
setPixel(x+1, y+1, true);
setPixel(x+2, y+2, true);
setPixel(x+3, y+3, true);
```

But naturally, it overlapped when I tried to draw something. How should I call the method?

> While I'm tagging this Java, the concept could apply to any language.

Comment: It's not only *tagged* java, it's also in the title. In general, the solution could be trivial, but note that depending on the implementation of the actual `setPixel` method (and depending on the language and graphics environment), there may be **far** better solutions than a generic, straight-forward one.

Answer (score 1):

Answering on these assumptions: setPixel sets a single pixel to white or black (if *on* is true, to black, else to white). You want to use this function to get a B&W image and make it four times larger. The code you provided is wrong and just makes a diagonal instad of a 4x4 block. Is this correct? If so:

A way to draw a 4 times larger image would then be, for example, to have a "getPixel(x,y)" which gets you whether the pixel at (x,y) is *on* in the original image and then start painting **somewhere else** in 4x4 blocks. Whenever you move by one pixel in either X or Y direction when getting the values of your original image, you move by 4 in your new image to scale. So then what you intended to do maybe was something like this?

```
void setBlock(int x, int y, boolean on, int scale)
    for(int i=0; i < scale; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < scale; j++){
            setPixel(scale*x + i, scale*y + j, on);
```

And then iterate over your original image's coordinates doing something like this?

```
setBlock(x, y, getPixel(x, y), 4);
```